# Dual boot Problem with windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

i made dual boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04,but after installing the Windows Drivers the Computer is not showing the option to choose between Windows and Ubuntu..it is directly moving to Windows..Why???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean after installing the windows drivers, or after installing Windows?  My guess is that you installed Ubuntu first, then Windows, and after installing Windows you saw this problem.

Windows doesn't know about the GRUB2 bootloader (the menu used to select between different operating systems) and writes its own bootloader when you install it.

You need to reinstall and reconfigure GRUB2.  [This](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) looks like a reasonably detailed description of how to do it, but there are other ways (google, now you know what you're trying to achieve) if that doesn't suit you.

Comment: i have installed Windows first, after that i installed Ubuntu and installed the windows Drivers at last.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "installed the Windows drivers" - drivers for what?  Anyway, I strongly suspect you need to repair GRUB2 as per both answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed ubuntu first and than windows. If Yes, then you should go with the software **Boot-Repair-Disk** 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/
Boot-Repair-Disk is a live CD that repairs multiple Linux distributions. Boot-Repair Disk repairs the GRUB boot loader of Linux and can repair multiple editions of Microsoft Windows operating systems.
Instructions to use **Boot-Repair-Disk** are on links below
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair